# How to write case statments

Tags: sql, netezza

I have two tables(ABC,CDE) in my Netezza. I need to write the following list of case statement  to display value.

Tables and Columns:

Table name ABC: 
Column:           (Id(PK), Desc)

Table name CDE:
Columns:        (value(like 1, 2, 3), ID(FK))

```
select case when value Is Not Null then 'CALIFORNIA' else ID end 
from CDE
```

NZ displays pg atoi (I think it is unable to do the conversion for ID to varchar)

How to write CASE using `NZ`?

Comment: Perhaps simply cast the ID to varchar.  so `case when value Is Not Null then cast('CALIFORNIA' as varchar(50)) else cast(Id as varchar(50)) end`  pg atoi: "The error is the result of an implicit conversion being performed on a character field (varchar/char) while being compared to a numeric field or value."

Comment: what role does table ABC have in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN value IS NOT NULL THEN 'CALIFORNIA'
        ELSE TO_CHAR(ID)
    END 
FROM CDE;
```

Comment: Hi Rogue ,  I think neteeza this will return CHAR(int) function but doesn't return the data.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(50))
```

or

```
|      Function         |  Return Type  |       Description          |
======================================================================
| to_char(int, text)    |     text      | converts integer to string |
```

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN value IS NOT NULL THEN 'CALIFORNIA'
        ELSE to_char(ID, text)
    END 
FROM CDE;
```